Vue setup using extends report errors in prod but normal in dev
I using extends option with setup SFCs, it report an error in production, but normal in dev.
Examples as below:
import Base from './Base.vue'
export default {
  extends: Base,
  setup(props, ctx) {
    return {
      ...Base.setup(props, ctx),
      // 本地绑定
    }
  }
}


The question lacks clear problem statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "it report an error" - which is? What is the setup and what do you do exactly to run it in dev and prod?

in development, vue setup function return an object, but in production, it returns a render function, so couldn't use ... to convert.  Any solution to resolve this?

this issue can be link to https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/2811 @EstusFlask

Please, list the error exactly in the question and mention where you see it. And explain your setup, which could be relevant. You already know the problem you deal with but other users don't.
